# can't refresh a rails html div with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

the following renders "2" in the div as it should when a form is submitted.

full brands/create.js.erb version 1:

```
$("#brand_ajax").html("1")

$("#brand_ajax").html("0")

$("#brand_ajax").html("2")
```

partial brands/show_brands.html.erb
**The div I want to refresh**

```
<% for brand in @brands%>
   ID: <%= h brand.id %>
<% end %>
```

partial cars/show.html.erb
**The ajax call**

```
<%= form_for([@car, @car.brands.build], **remote: true**) do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :brandsdo |a| %>
<%= a.text_field :name, placeholder: "New Manufacturer" %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit "+", class: "btn inline" %>
<% end %>

**/*The div I want to refresh*/**
<div id="brand_ajax">
<%= render 'brands/show_brands' %>
</div>
```

The brands controller

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @brand.save
      format.html { redirect_to @car }
      format.js
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error!"
      format.html { redirect_to @car }
     end
end
```

the following does not render "2" after submitting a new brands form - does not refresh at all. just shows the old version of
'show_brands'.

full brands/create.js.erb (to illustrate)

```
$("#brand_ajax").html("1")

$("#brand_ajax").html("<%= escape_javascript render 'show_brands' %>")

$("#brand_ajax").html("2")
```

any ideas why such a thing should happen?

Comment: are you getting any errors? what is being rendered?

Comment: no errors. just a list of brands without the latest brand. the latest brand appears after a manual page refresh.

Comment: is this all the code?

Comment: added some more code to illustrate better

Comment: could you paste some more code?  what you mean by submitting form?? Is it making ajax call?? Can u post ur complete javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#brand_ajax").html("<%= j render :partial => 'show_brands' %>")
```